# Why does axios interceptors go into an infinite loop when trying to update a token?

Tags: reactjs

I have *access_token* and *refresh_token* in `localStorage`.

Before calling my backend, I want to check if the token has expired:

```
 instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      const auth = jwt_decode(accessToken);
      const expireTime = auth.exp * 1000;
      const now = + new Date();
      if (expireTime > now) {
        console.log("true");
        config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
      } else {
        console.log("false");
        (async() => {
          const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
          const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
          const data = response.data;
          const token = data.accessToken;
          setAuth({token,refreshToken});
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", token);
          config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        })();        
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

*refresh token method*

```
 const refreshAccessToken = async (token) => {
    return instance.post("/refresh", token);
  };
```

And this code works until I add a line:

```
const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
```

After that, when the token expires, the page freezes indefinitely in a repeat of the false branch although I am putting a new token in the storage.

I will be glad if someone tells me what's wrong, maybe I'm doing something wrong with interceptors?

*refresh response*:

```
{
    "accessToken": "...",
    "refreshToken": "..."
}
```

Comment: `refreshAccessToken` does `instance.post`, which will trigger the interceptor, right? Which will call `refreshAccessToken`, which...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed, and I didn't even notice.And what happens is it necessary to do several interceptors?